# Form onclick not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently learning JS and trying to create a validation function to see if the fields are empty or not. When I click the submit button I expect to see something in the JS console in Chrome but am not seeing anything. Why would this not be echoing anything into the console?

```
var field1 = document.getElementById("field1");
var field2 = document.getElementById("field2");
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

function validate() {

    if(field1 === "" || field2 === "") {
      console.log("Make sure all fields have been filled out correctly");
    } else {
      console.log("they are full");
    }
}  


<form action="" action="get">
     <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter something"/>
     <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter that thing again"/>
     <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" value="Submit" onclick="return validate()" />
</form>
```

Comment: You need to make sure your JS comes after your HTML. All JS should go directly above the </body> tag.

Comment: When that JavaScript is processed those elements don't exist yet.

Comment: Ah, so put them below the body?

Comment: Just before the closing body tag.

Comment: also its field1.value and field2.value to check if the values are empty

Comment: Simple mistake, my fault. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are not submitting the form make you just make it a button instead of submit .Submit makes the form to be submitted

Please check the following code snippet

```js
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

function validate() {
var field1 = document.getElementById("field1").value;
var field2 = document.getElementById("field2").value;
  if (field1 === "" || field2 === "") {
    console.log("Make sure all fields have been filled out correctly");
  } else {
    console.log("they are full");
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" action="get">
  <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter something" />
  <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter that thing again" />
  <input type="button" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" value="Submit" onclick="return validate()" />
</form>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: But if the validate function passes I want the form to be submitted?

Comment: You can make the functionality as if it passes the validation form to be submitted ...if you dont want the page to reload make it just type="button" or else just remain it as "submit"

Comment: Testing your code it only generates the first message. `var field1` and `var field2` should be defined in the validate function otherwise it will always do that

Answer (score 1):

Form submit will post data back causing a refresh and you might not be able to see the console logs before that.

Add return false after console.log to capture the data. Also, you need to use element.value instead of element to get the value while comparing it against empty condition. In case you want to submit when validation passes, add return true.

here is the working fiddle for your example:

```html
<form action="" action="get">
     <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter something"/>
     <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter that thing again"/>
     <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" value="Submit" onclick="return validate()" />
</form>
<script>
var field1 = document.getElementById("field1");
var field2 = document.getElementById("field2");
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

function validate() {

    if(field1.value === "" || field2.value === "") {
      console.log("Make sure all fields have been filled out correctly");
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log("they are full");
      return false;
    }
    
}  

</script>
```